# Como saber onde um script específico está sendo executado em determinado elemento HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, script, console

Tem um javascript executando em uma determinada página, gostaria de descobri onde ele está, ou seja o caminho ou pelo menos o nome. Por exemplo: "./files/global.js.download". Tenho uma página que tem vários com js, se for apagando um dá pra descobri mas é muito trabalhoso, deve existir uma maneira de ir direto, de cara e saber o qual a gente precisa alterar/exclui.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você ja experimentou em clicar com o direito no texto e inspecionar
dai você pode ver como o texto chama a função script

Comment: Só uma dúvida você que fez esta página?

Comment: A forma como o amigo @Gabriel disse funciona mas se a rotina foi setada como um manipulador de evento dentro de seu JS, nenhuma chamada vai conter no seu html. O evento estará dentro de seu javascript, nesse caso aperte o F12 para abrir o seu "Developer Tools" e na guia network procure os javascript que estão sendo carregados na página. Com certeza dentro de algum JS vai encontrar um manipulador chamando algum rotina JS responsável pelo efeito.

Comment: Exato , @RafaelSalomão , porém ele teria que deletar os arquivos do mesmo jeito ou ficar um bom tempo procurando , não teria um jeito de pesquisar este evento?

Comment: A pergunta dele é legitíma, não sei o porque deram downvote!

Comment: Eu consigo encontrar, mas a única forma que sei é indo excluindo um a um pra achar, mas são mais de 200, só queria achar uma maneira mais fácil.

Comment: Manda a url dessa página quer quer o efeito. Edite sua pergunta e adicione  URL da página

Comment: https://goo.gl/89WX8d

Comment: Você quer saber como fazer com que fique mudando o texto igual nesse site ?